# I want to bind a function to a label in tkinter, been boggling me

Tags: python, function, tkinter, widget

I am still learning so bare with me

Basic explanation of the program:
Using Python3, and the tkinter module, I am making a little GUI just to learn the basics.
In the GUI there is a button, the idea is that when you click the button, a random verse of text (from a txt file) is displayed in another widget within the gui (a label in this case).

I can get the program to pull random verses from the text file, and print them in the shell, but not in the gui widget.

The code requires 2 files, the .py and the .txt

I uploaded them to a github repo so it may be easier to get an idea of the program there

[Link to the project on github](https://github.com/raseribanez/Python-and-Buddhism)

However I will put the .py code here if it is more convenient that way but it won't run without the txt file.

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)  
        self.parent = parent
        
    def random_line():
        line_num = 0
        selected_line = ''
        with open('dhammapada.txt') as f:
            while 1:
                line = f.readline()
                if not line: break
                line_num += 1 
                if random.uniform(0, line_num) < 1:
                    selected_line = line
        return(selected_line.strip())         


    def print_a_verse():
        print('\n',random_line())

    btn_result = Button(self, fg='Gold', text='New Verse', bg='Black', font='freesansbold, 16', command=print_a_verse) #textvariable=cvt_to, font='freesansbold, 16', fg='Blue')
    btn_result.pack(fill=X,side=BOTTOM)#fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    lbl_one = Label(self, bg='DarkGrey', fg='White',  text='Dhammapada', font='freesansbold, 22')
    lbl_one.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    lbl_thr = Label(self, bg='DarkGrey', fg='White', text='The Dhammapada \nSiddartha Gautama - Buddha', font='freesansbold, 18')
    lbl_thr.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    lbl_two = Label(self, bg='DarkGrey', fg='Grey')
    lbl_two.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.minsize(400,400)
    #root.configure(bg='Black')
    root.title('Python - Dhammapada Verses')
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

I started that repo a few years back when I first got into coding, I was self-teaching online then because of pretty severe epilepsy I had to pretty much abandon sitting in front of a screen for hours so stopped it all. I think it was 2016. This is the first program I have looked at since, and the subject matter of the book has helped me a lot over the years.

I hope somebody can point me in the right direction. I may be making a mess of the whole thing already!

EDIT:

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
```

Comment: Why do you have code at the indentation level of method definitions? It would be a good idea to move that code inside your `__init__` method.

Comment: I can't post code here so I'll edit it into the end of the main post, but do you mean like this? ^^^

Comment: I get what you mean, working on it now

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        btn_result = Button(self, fg='Gold', text='New Verse', bg='Black', font='freesansbold, 16', command=self.print_a_verse) #textvariable=cvt_to, font='freesansbold, 16', fg='Blue')
        btn_result.pack(fill=X,side=BOTTOM)#fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        lbl_one = Label(self, bg='DarkGrey', fg='White',  text='Dhammapada', font='freesansbold, 22')
        lbl_one.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        lbl_thr = Label(self, bg='DarkGrey', fg='White', text='The Dhammapada \nSiddartha Gautama - Buddha', font='freesansbold, 18')
        lbl_thr.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        lbl_two = Label(self, bg='DarkGrey', fg='Grey')
        lbl_two.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    def random_line(self):
        return "testing text" # Just for testing
        line_num = 0
        selected_line = ''
        with open('dhammapada.txt') as f:
            while 1:
                line = f.readline()
                if not line: break
                line_num += 1
                if random.uniform(0, line_num) < 1:
                    selected_line = line
        return(selected_line.strip())

    def print_a_verse(self):
        print(self.random_line())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.minsize(400, 400)
    #root.configure(bg='Black')
    root.title('Python - Dhammapada Verses')
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

I moved all of the widget definitions inside your `__init__` method and added `self` where appropriate to make sure it doesn't raise any errors. I would also suggest that you look at a quick object oriented programming tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by only reading from the text file once, and storing all verses in a list. The way your code is written now, any time you call `random_line`, you're opening the file and closing it, which seems unnecessary.

Your method of selecting a random line isn't perfect, and could also be simplified - you read through the file, line by line, and occassionally decide to reassign `selected_line` depending on whether some random number is below an arbitrary threshold. There are several issues with this - there is no mechanism that prevents `selected_line` from being overwritten multiple times (which is unnecessary). There is also no guarantee that `selected_line` will ever be overwritten from its initial empty state. Additionally, the random number is generated via `random.uniform(0, line_num)` - since `line_num` increases with each iteration, the likelyhood that the random number will be below your threshold diminishes with each iteration. As a result, lines that are closer to the top of the file are more likely to be chosen.

The solution is to simply use `random.choice` to randomly select a verse from a list of all possible verses:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Random Verse")
        self.geometry("256x256")
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Click", command=self.on_click)
        self.button.pack()

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="", wraplength=200)
        self.label.pack()

        self.verses = self.get_verses("dhammapada.txt")

    def get_verses(self, file_name):
        with open(file_name, "r") as file:
            verses = file.read().splitlines()
        return verses

    def on_click(self):
        from random import choice
        self.label["text"] = choice(self.verses)


def main():
    Application().mainloop()
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Given that OP isn't very familiar with OOP, wouldn't it be better to stick with inheriting from `tk.Frame`? Also why don't you move the `from random import choice` to the top of the code?

Comment: Yes, I can see how `*args, **kwargs` might just add confusion, though I think the core of the code can be easily understood. I'm happy to make changes if it turns out to be not as intuitive as I thought. The local import is just a habit, and can be imported at the top, by all means.